# How to assign a string-variable to a StackString based on the StackString-library?

Tags: string

I'm trying to use the StackString-library which offers not to eat up RAM over time by re-assigning values to strings. I started from scratch and wrote a very basic democode which works.
Then I added an assignment to a STackString-variable from a normal string or a function with return-value string
See code below
If I try to compile 
I get a compiler-error saying
no matching function for call to 'Stack::StackString<50>::append(String&)'

here is the code

```
#include <StackString.hpp> 
using namespace Stack;  // it is very important to have this line of code. Otherwise the code won't compile

StackString<50> myString = StackString<50>("Hello, World!");

String NormalString = "1234Test";

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(myString.c_str());

  myString.prepend("Everybody say: ");
  Serial.println(myString.c_str());

  myString.append(" How are you doing?");
  Serial.println(myString.c_str());
  Serial.println();

  //myString = NormalString;
  myString.append(NormalString);


}

void loop() 
{ // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Do I have to do some typecasting? and if yes how does it look like?
WHat I want to do is assigning a StackString a new value. This means the STackString is on the left side of the "="  assigning operator. I have tried different variants to no avail.

Could this be a problem of the special construction as a "namespace" ?
No idea no clue

you find the STackString-library here:
https://gitlab.com/arduino-libraries/stackstring

best regards

Stefan

Comment: Are char arrays really so daunting that people go to this length to avoid them?  Why struggle with this when you could just write a char array and be done with it?

Comment: You are writing this from a position of beeing an expert about arrays of char, c-strings etc. This does explain nothing to come nearer to the point of enough knowledge to use your preferred way of using "strings". So a much more productive comment would be to explain how it works. Not with a most short and elegant single line of code but with a thoroughly explained example with lots of comments or additional text.

Answer (score 0):

`StackString` doesn't know what a `String` is.  The `append` function only accepts a `const char *`, a `const char` or an `int`:

```
void append(const char* string);
void append(const char character);
void append(int number);
```

You can get a `const char *` from a `String` easily enough with `.c_str()`, so use that in the append:

```
myString.append(NormalString.c_str());
```

There is also no simple assignment (or complete content replacement) with `StackString` - you have to "clear" the string first.  So to replace the content with what is in `NormalString` you would:

```
myString.clear();
myString.append(NormalString.c_str());
```